# Dynamic Variables stored in object not updating value when changed

Tags: javascript, object, dom, ecmascript-6

I stored dynamic variables in an object called newEvent. The variables values change, but when I store them in newEvent they keep the same value that they had when they were first loaded and they don't change values when they are updated. Here is my code

```
let headerMonths = document.getElementsByClassName('month')[0];
let headerYears = document.getElementsByClassName('year')[0]; 

let newEvent = {
    // day: parseInt(event.innerHTML),
    title: document.querySelector('#new-event-title'),
    desc: document.querySelector('#new-event-desc'),
    month: headerMonths.innerHTML,
    year: headerYears.innerHTML,
    active: document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0],
    submit: ()=>{
        if(newEvent.title.value.length===0){
            console.log('sasc');
            newEvent.title.classList.add('error');
        } else if(newEvent.desc.value.length===0) {
            newEvent.desc.classList.add('error');
        } else {
            newEventJson(newEvent.title.value, newEvent.desc.value, newEvent.month, newEvent.year, newEvent.active.innerHTML);
        }
    }
 };

 document.querySelector('#submit-event').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    newEvent.submit();
 });
```

The only variables whose values are changing in newEvent are newEvent.title and newEvent.desc, which are html input's inside a form. Why is this happening and how can I get the changed valued of the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to this

```
let newEvent = {
    // day: parseInt(event.innerHTML),
    title: document.querySelector('#new-event-title'),
    desc: document.querySelector('#new-event-desc'),
    month: headerMonths,
    year: headerYears,
    active: document.getElementsByClassName('active'),
    submit: ()=>{
        if(newEvent.title.value.length===0){
            console.log('sasc');
            newEvent.title.classList.add('error');
        } else if(newEvent.desc.value.length===0) {
            newEvent.desc.classList.add('error');
        } else {
            newEventJson(newEvent.title.value, newEvent.desc.value, newEvent.month.innerHTML, newEvent.year.innerHTML, newEvent.active[0].innerHTML);
        }
    }
 };
```

and now the values are updating. It must be because when I declared the object keys I accessed the current value of the element before I changed it and it never updated when I call the submit function, but now the direct value or html of the element is only accessed when I call the newEvent.submit function and this is getting my changes to those elements.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that title and description are the only values changing is because you're setting them in `newEvent` as the query selector result for their corresponding DOM element. Whereas the other values including month, year and active, are either strings or numbers/bools.

Comment: I'm getting the value of the element from newEvent.title and newEvent.desc, I get the other elements directly through their class name and I access their innerHTML which changes. if I type these selectors in my browser console I get the correct value that they are changed to, but it doesn't change in the newEvent object. Do I have to use a query Selector to get the changes of the element?